# django nested model json import

Tags: json, django, django-rest-framework

I am quite new to Django and I may be missunderstanding some concepts, but I can not find a solution to what I am trying to do.

I have a multi table model defined and I have defined the models, views, admin, serializers and urls. It is working perfectly to independtly read and write in all of them through the API.

The code looks something like this:

models.py

```
class Level1(MySQLNoCountModel):
    name = models.CharField()
...

class Level2(MySQLNoCountModel):

    level1 = models.ForeignKey(
        Level1,
        blank=False,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    name = models.CharField()
    )
...
```

serializers.py

```
class CreateLevel1Serializer(OrderedModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()

    def create(self, validated_data):
        obj, created = models.Level1.objects.update_or_create(
            name = validated_data['name'],
            defaults={
            }
        )


class CreateLevel2Serializer(OrderedModelSerializer):
    level1 = serializers.CharField()
    name = serializers.CharField()

    def validate_level1(self, value):
        try:
            return models.Level1.objects.get(
                name=value
            )
        except Exception:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(_('Invalid leve1'))

    def create(self, validated_data):
        obj, created = models.Level2.objects.update_or_create(
            name = validated_data['name'],
            defaults={
                'level1': validated_data.get('level1', True),
            }
        )
```

With this I can create new elements by sending two consecutive posts to the specific ednpoints:

```
{
    "name":"name1"
}

{
    "level1":"name1",
    "name":"name2"
}
```

I am trying to do it in a single operation by inserting something like this:

```
{
    "name":"name1"
    "level2":[
        {
            "name":"name2"
        },
        {
            "name":"name3"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have tryied to redefine the level1 serializer like this but It tryes to create the level2 before the level1, resulting on a validation error.

```
class CreateLevel1Serializer(OrderedModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()
    level2 = CreateLevel2Serializer(many=True)
```

What is the correct approach for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a way to do it (don't know if it is the regular one). On the creation of the Level1 we can call the level2 serializer. Something like this:

class CreateLevel1Serializer(OrderedModelSerializer):
name = serializers.CharField()

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    obj, created = models.Level1.objects.update_or_create(
        name = validated_data['name'],
        defaults={
        }
    )
    for level2 in request.data.get('level2'):
        level2serializer = CreateLevel2Serializer(data=level2)
        r=level2serializer .is_valid()
        level2inst = level2serializer .save()
```